# How to get the underlying stdio FILE* of a managed System.IO.FileStream?

Tags: .net, c++, filestream, stdio

I'm writing a .NET adaptor for a C/C++ library where a method "bar" takes a regular stdio FILE*. Is it possible to build an interface so that managed code user can pass a managed (File)Stream? That is without creating an intermediary buffer and code to pipe the data between. Also does the assumption that bar() reads only make things any better?

```
// native code
void bar(FILE*);

// interface for managed code
void foo(System::IO::FileStream^ file)
{
    FILE* stdio_handle = ???;

    bar(stdio_handle);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`System.IO.FileStream.Handle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.handle.aspx)

It's not necessarily `stdio` handle. It's a Windows handle. I don't think `FileStream` is built upon `stdio` to have a `stdio` handle.

As Marc pointed out and mentioned in the MSDN link, you might want to consider using `SafeFileHandle` property (if you are on .NET 2.0+) instead of `Handle` (which is now considered obsolete). Only `Handle` is available in older versions, though.

Comment: Valid concern. Updated the answer to reflect.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to build an interface
>   so that managed code user can pass a
>   managed (File)Stream?

No, it's not possible to convert a stream to a file descriptor (`FILE`*).

Answer (score 0):

If you have to have a stdio handle, you could always use fopen to open the file in the first place. [This](http://weblogs.asp.net/ralfw/archive/2006/03/04/439580.aspx) describes a wrapper to export the c stdlib file functions and then he uses interop to work with them.